# How can ModelState.Remove can be used to exclude IFormFile from Validation?

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations, iformfile

My model has an IFormFile attribute, which handles a file uploaded by the user. This attribute has the Required data annotation since it is required in certain views.
However, not all the views need to have the file submitted by the user. There are some views, where the file upload is optional and not mandatory.

I tried using ModelState.Remove("FileAtrributeName") and ModelState.Remove(nameof(ModelName.FileAtrributeName) to exclude the required validation from the controller handling the views which do not require this validation, but it is always being included in the client validation.
The ModelState.Remove works with model attributes of string type, since validation is not applied on client and server side (when using the if(ModelState.IsValid)).
Is there an alternative way of excluding required validation on the file in some views?
I also need to excluded from the ModelState.Required after the form is submitted (without the file).

This code sample shows how the IFormFile is declared in the model

```
    [DisplayName("Invoice File")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invoice File is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile? InvoiceFile {  get; set; }
```

This code shows how I am trying to exclude validation on it from the controller handling the view which does not require the validation on the file:

```
ModelState.Remove(nameof(invoice.InvoiceFile));
```

or

```
ModelState.Remove("InvoiceFile");
```

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.Remove only works on server side validation,

for client validation,you need to remove html required  attribute like`<input...... required="required">`

I suggest you create different ViewModel for different Views and Map them with your entity model

Comment: ModelState.Remove also removed validation for string attributes to my view. I initialised an object on the model, set the string attributes which are not required in that view with ModelState.Remove and, the required validation did not show up in my view. I need the same thing for the IFormFile, but ModelState.Remove does not appear to work with that type of attribute.

Comment: could you share more codes related so that I could foud what's wrong